# mv a file to /dev/null breaks dev/null

Tags: osx, devices, null

If I do: `touch file; mv file /dev/null` as root, `/dev/null` disappears.  `ls -lad /dev/null` results in no such file or directory.  This breaks applications which depend on `/dev/null` like SSH and can be resolved by doing `mknod /dev/null c 1 3; chmod 666 /dev/null`.  Why does moving a regular file to this special file result in the disappearance of `/dev/null`?

To clarify, this was for testing purposes, and I understand how the `mv` command works. What I am curious about is why `ls -la /dev/null` before replacing it with a regular file shows the expected output, but afterwards it shows that `/dev/null` does not exist even though a file was allegedly created via the original `mv` command and the file command shows ASCII Text.  I think this must be a combination of the `ls` command behavior in conjunction with `devfs` when a non special file replaces a character/special file.  This is on Mac OS X, behaviors may vary on other OS's.

Comment: Don't mess with `/dev/null`.

Comment: so says @devnull

Comment: The proper way to delete files is the `rm` command.

Comment: I am not trying to delete anything, this was an experiment.  The thing I am curious about is that replacing the file results in the file being missing when ls -la /dev/null is run.  I am guessing this is due to the nature of devfs.

Comment: @Gregg, does a Mac use `devfs`?

Comment: Yes df -h 

Greggs-MacBook-Air1:~ gleventhal$ df -h /dev
Filesystem   Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
devfs       191Ki  191Ki    0Bi   100%     660     0  100%   /dev

Comment: @Gregg, can you also create normal files on the OSX `/dev`, eg `touch /dev/testfile`.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not specific to `ls`, run `find /dev -n name null` to test whether `find` can see it. I really doubt it will but may as well.

Comment: On a Mac, as root touch /dev/test results in operation not supported.

Comment: Seems like that is the root of your problem, OSX `devfs` is funny about normal files. Strange you didn't get an error from `mv` though. How about this way: `touch testfile; mv testfile /dev`?

Comment: touch testfile; mv testfile /dev results in operation not supported too, so I am going to assume when you mv file /dev/null on a Mac you are "unlinking" /dev/null and then the mv fails, but this seems weird since mv is supposed to be atomic.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal So it was pointed out to me. I deleted my comment, but too late to stop you answering. :-) In the interest of reducing clutter, if you delete your comment, I'll delete mine. Just ping me on chat, and sorry about the noise.

Comment: @Gregg, `mv` can only be atomic on the same filesystem.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/bsdcon/full_papers/kamp/kamp_html/) @DE_WHITEOUT flag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the source code for mv, http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-220.7/mv/mv.c :

```
/*
 * If rename fails because we're trying to cross devices, and
 * it's a regular file, do the copy internally; otherwise, use
 * cp and rm.
 */
if (lstat(from, &sb)) {
    warn("%s", from);
    return (1);
}
return (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode) ?
    fastcopy(from, to, &sb) : copy(from, to));

...

int
fastcopy(char *from, char *to, struct stat *sbp)
{
...
while ((to_fd =
    open(to, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0)) < 0) {
        if (errno == EEXIST && unlink(to) == 0)
            continue;
        warn("%s", to);
        (void)close(from_fd);
        return (1);
}
```

In the first pass through the while loop, `open(to, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0)` will fail with EEXIST. Then `/dev/null` will be unlinked, and the loop repeated.
But as you pointed out in your comment, regular files can't be created in `/dev`, so on the next pass through the loop, `open(to, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0)` is still going to fail.

I'd file a bug report with Apple. The `mv` source code is mostly unchanged from the FreeBSD version, but because OSX's devfs has that non-POSIX behavior with regular files, Apple should fix their `mv`.

Comment: I am giving this best answer right now for providing source code and acknowledging this as a bug, which is what I was driving at.

Answer (score 12):

Moving a file to the location of an already existing file replaces the existing file. In this case the `/dev/null` device file is replaced, just as any normal file would be. To avoid this use the `-i` (interactive, warns before overwriting) or `-n` (no clober) option for `mv`.

`/dev/null` only performs its special function as a bit-bucket then the device is opened as is. Eg, when the `>` shell operator is used, the file is opened then truncated (not removed an replaced, which may be what you expected). As mentioned by casey, the correct way to remove a file is with `rm` or even with `unlink`.

Comment: See my comments to terdon.

Comment: Understood, the -d was unneeded, that is just a bad habit however the file should still show up in the ls output, it should not show as nonexistent.

Comment: @Graeme - welcome to 3K, nice job!

Answer (score 10):

Umm, because you overwrite the special file with  normal one? What did you expect to happen? `dev/null` is not a directory, it is a file pointing to a `null` device. When you `mv` something to it, you delete the original and replace it with whatever you moved:

```
$ file /dev/null 
/dev/null: character special 
$ sudo mv file /dev/null 
$ file /dev/null 
/dev/null: ASCII text
```

Comment: But I am saying /dev/null was showing as missing when running an ls -lad /dev/null.  This must be something specific to the devfs, that it what I wanted to know about.

Comment: If I mv file /dev/null then /dev/null should contain what file contained but still exist.  I want to know why this caused /dev/null to not be found in an ls.

Comment: Granted, I am doing this on a Mac, so it might be slightly different, but I did not expect the file to show as missing, I only expected it to show as changed to the source file.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal yes, it must be an OSX or BSD thing (please edit your Q and specify your OS). On my Linux I can still see `/dev/null`, it's just become the file I moved.